# No ProjectInfo.xml files were found .TFS build with sonar end task

Tags: tfs, build

I am trying to configure my visual studio project to send some analysis data to SonarQube server using TFS 2015 build (vnext)
I get this error in the Sonar end task.
 ##[error]No ProjectInfo.xml files were found. Possible causes: 
 ##[error]1. The project has not been built - the end step was called right after the begin step, without a build step in between
 An unsupported version of MSBuild has been used to build the project. Currently MSBuild 12.0 upwards are supported

We use MSBuild 14.0 in the server.

Comment: it is a VC++ project with .vcxproj project file

Answer (score 0):

> The SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild requires your project to be built
> with MSBuild 14.0. We recommend installing Visual Studio 2015 on the
> analysis machine in order to benefit from the integration and features
> provided with the Visual Studio ecosystem (VSTest, MSTest unit tests,
> etc.).

Suggest you to also install VS2015 on your build server, and since you are using MSbuild 14.0, double check if you are using the old task with **deprecated** in front which used for MSbuild 12.0. [SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild released](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/01/04/sonarqube-scanner-for-msbuild-v1-1-released-static-analysis-now-executed-during-the-build/) with *static analysis* which could executed during the build on MSbuild 14.0.

> The support of MSBuild 12 by the SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild is
> **deprecated** and will be removed in a future release.
>
> Source: [Compatibility with Visual Studio and MSBuild](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Compatibility)

[image]

Please **download and use the latest version** of the [SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SonarSource.sonarqube) in marketplace and try again. The recent documentation is available from [Analyzing with SonarQube Extension for VSTS/TFS](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Extension+for+VSTS-TFS), you could also take a look at this tutorial.