# No ProjectInfo.xml files were found Sonar scan

Tags: tfs, build

I am trying to configure my visual studio project to send some scan data to SonarQube server using TFS 2015 build (vnext)
I get this error in the Sonar end task.

```
##[error]No ProjectInfo.xml files were found. Possible causes: 
##[error]1. The project has not been built
```

The end step was called right after the begin step, without a build step in between an unsupported version of MSBuild has been used to build the project. Currently MSBuild 12.0 upwards are supported.

We use MSBuild 14.0 in the server. it is a C++ project (VCXPROJ project File)

Comment: Please avoid submitting two identical question in so to make community clean. You could directly edit your question to supplement information. Since you have created [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42812107/no-projectinfo-xml-files-were-found-tfs-build-with-sonar-end-task), suggest you to delete this question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No ProjectInfo.xml files were found .TFS build with sonar end task](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42812107/no-projectinfo-xml-files-were-found-tfs-build-with-sonar-end-task)

Comment: What're steps of your build definition? Can you share the detail build log here?